# how to check if given variable is a collection of html elements?

Tags: javascript

For example a type of data that `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` produces.

Comment: Are you asking how to verify if anything was returned by the method, or whether or not the element collection contains only HTML elements?

Comment: Second. Whether collection contains only HTML elements.

Comment: That's an odd question because getElementsBy* returns HTML elements by definition. What type of data are you expecting to be returned? Is there some other type of collection you're referring to?

Comment: In any case, you can check to see whether nodeType = 1.

Comment: @squidbe Actually, they can be used on XML documents as well, so RSS, ATOM, et al could return non-HTML nodes.

Comment: True, @Tieson. user393087, what's the context here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if (result && result.constructor.name == "NodeList"){
// your code here ;)
}
```

or this could be more browser safe

```
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if (result && getClassName(result) == "htmlcollection"){
// your code here ;)
}     
function getClassName(obj){
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function isCollection(input)
{
    return input.item != undefined;
}
```

But beware any other objects with the method `item` defined.